send variable data to Zebra printer to print GS1-128 code
i have this  ZPL code iam trying to send it a Zebra printer ,  i am trying to send this  batch file that contains then variable data  but actually it is not printed
iam asking , whats is wrong withthis code to print GS1-128 code
thanks
^XA
^DFE:TEMPLATE.ZPL^FS  ; Use the template file
^FO130,120^A0N,31,30^FH\^CI28^FDGS1-128^FS
^BY2,3,54^FO110,134^BCN,,N,N
^FO50,50^FD>;>^FN2^FN1^FS  ; GS1-128 barcode using FN1
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ



^XA
^XFE:TEMPLATE.ZPL^FS  ; Use the template again
^FN1^FD08932490808750329048023^FS  ; Assign data to FN1
^FN2^FD(01)
^PQ1
^XZ

i tried surfing the internet for any support  but still cannot find the problem
